Unable to handle special charecters symbol in github actions powershell task
I save ↓ DEV_BL_MYHOST or this ↑ DEV_BL_MYHOST in the database using the below query.
$updateQuery = "UPDATE $Database.[dbo].[tbl_myinventory] SET custompackage = NCHAR(8593) + ' '

I read back these from the database using Select statement and then perform several task on the data like storing it as JSON and using it as Github Action Matrix as "â†“ DEV_BL_MYHOST" and â†‘ DEV_BL_MYHOST.
Upon reading back in github actions workflow powershell step it prints with special charecters like below:
  Write-Host 'Tracker12 - "${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }}"'
  $displayList = '${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }}'
  $splitList = $displayList.Split(' ')
  $trackerValue = $splitList[1]
  Write-Host "Tracker15 - $trackerValue"
  echo "approveenvName=$trackerValue" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
  $splitstring = '${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }}'
  $envName = (($splitstring -split '_', 2)[0] -split ' ', 2)[1]


Run Write-Host 'Tracker12 - "↓ DEV_BL_MYHOST"'
Tracker12 - "â†“ DEV_BL_MYHOST"

Run $splitstring = '↑ DEV_BL_MYHOST'
At D:\Git-Runners\selfhostdrunner\_work\_temp\c7b0bbb2-5de5-4278-ba2d-75f7c02f1351.ps1:3 char:21
+ $splitstring = 'â†‘ DEV_BL_MYHOST'

As you can see i'm neither able to use single quotes or double quotes around the variable that reads this data from the database i.e ${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }} as one of them is destinted to error.
My requirement is to just get rid of anything before the white space and just gather DEV_BL_MYHOST from ↑ DEV_BL_MYHOST in powershell.
I tried using replace function to resolve this like below:
      $splitstring = '${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }}'

      # Remove specific special characters using regular expressions
      $modifiedString = $splitstring -replace '[â†‘â†“]', 'X'

But it fails on the first line itself $splitstring = '${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }}'
Note: i do not wish to read or restore UP or DOWN arrow symbols so any workaround that gets me just the Text part DEV_BL_MYHOST will help.

Fwiw, this looks like an encoding problem - something is encoding the string ↓ DEV_BL_MYHOST into a byte representation using UTF8, and then something else is decoding those bytes using a different encoding - possible candidates are "windows-1252" or "iso-8859-1" - e.g. [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("↓ DEV_BL_MYHOST")) results in â†“ DEV_BL_MYHOST

Agreed @mclayton so how do i handle this considering I just care and need the part after the whitespace i.e DEV_BL_MYHOST and the string changing from ↓ DEV_BL_MYHOST to ↑ DEV_BL_MYHOST

@mclayton i can't even try-catch  and switch between the desired quotes (Single or Double). Tried the below but that too fails:
try {     $originalText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("â†" DEV_BL_MYHOST"))     Write-Host "Original Text: $originalText" } catch {     $originalText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('â†" DEV_BL_MYHOST'))     Write-Host "Original Text: $originalText" }

Encoding problem
Per comments, your core problem is an encoding issue. You're starting with an in memory string with the value ↓ DEV_BL_MYHOST and somewhere along the line something is mishandling an encoded byte representation of the string  which means you end up with the in-memory string â†“ DEV_BL_MYHOST.
You can see that in action with the following code:
$original = "↓ DEV_BL_MYHOST"

# encode the string into a byte representation using the UTF* encoding
$encodedBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($original)

# encoded bytes are stored somewhere and then retrieved later...
$retrievedBytes = $encodedBytes

# incorrectly decode the encoded bytes using the wrong encoding -
# this is the root of the problem. it *should* use the same encoding
# (i.e. UTF8) as was used to encode the bnytes in the first place
$decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetString($retrievedBytes)

$decoded
# â†“ DEV_BL_MYHOST

It's worth trying to solve that problem even if you're only interested in the DEV_BL_MYHOST part of the string as you might end up with mangled text in that part too at some point in the future.
Substitution problem
Unfortunately, both of your mangled strings contain alternative PowerShell string delimiter characters - i.e. “ and ‘ so when they get substituted into the source code for your GitHub Actions one or the other of them generates invalid PowerShell code regardless of whether you use double or single quotes in your code:
# ↓ DEV_BL_MYHOST
Write-Host "Tracker12 - 'â†“ DEV_BL_MYHOST'"
#                          ^ string value contains an alternative double-quote

# ↑ DEV_BL_MYHOST
Write-Host 'Tracker12 - "â†‘ DEV_BL_MYHOST"'
#                          ^ string value contains an alternative single-quote

A safer way to pass the parameters would be to set them as environment variables in your GitHub Actions step, and then read them from the environment in your PowerShell script:
  - name: do stuff
    env:
      DISPLAY_LIST: ${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }}
    run: |
      $trackerValue = ($env:DISPLAY_LIST).Split(" ")[1]
      Write-Host "Tracker12 - '$trackerValue'"

If you don't want to do that, another option might be to get the Actions to json-encode the string using the toJson expression before substituting it into your code, and then reverse the encoding yourself:
  - name: do stuff
    run: |
      $displayList = "${{ toJson( matrix.DISPLAYLIST ) }}" | convertfrom-json
      $trackerValue = $displayList.Split(" ")[1]
      Write-Host "Tracker12 - '$trackerValue'"

That should escape the special characters and allow them to be substituted directly into the PowerShell code without breaking the syntax.
